# How to configure Django publication settings

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set apache to Django publication, but I got this message:

> "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Already, there is a running web service using **`/var/www/html`** as a document root.
I have add some configuration settings for Django publications at there. Please, refer to below.

```
# httpd.conf

...
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
....

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
...

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
...
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/eachone/Project/MW_Service/MW_Service/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess MW_Service python-path=/home/eachone/Project/MW_Service
WSGIProcessGroup MW_Service

<Directory /home/eachone/Project/MW_Service>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/eachone/Project/MW_Service/static/
<Directory /home/eachone/Project/MW_Service/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Did you check your apache logs (e.g. /var/log/httpd/error.log)... suggest posting the last 10 lines or so after you reload apache and then try to access the site.

Comment: [Wed Aug 12 22:33:39 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/4.4.14 Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 12 22:33:44 2015] [error] [client 1.243.129.189] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Wed Aug 12 22:34:46 2015] [error] [client 1.243.129.189] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Wed Aug 12 22:36:39 2015] [error] [client 1.243.129.189] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied

Comment: I had been programming using python 3.4. but Python 2.6.6 is configured. How to change to Python3.4?